# EntityFramework Core 3.0 Fluent API Many-to-many relationship builder creating extra foreign key columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

The issue is that EF core is creating extra foreign key columns for a many-to-many relationship, even though I've specified what the foreign keys are.

I have the following entity models, which need to be in a many-to-many relationship

`ParticipantModel.cs`

```
public class ParticipantModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public HashSet<ThreadsParticipants> ThreadsParticipants { get; set; } = new HashSet<ThreadsParticipants>();
}
```

`ThreadModel.cs`

```
public class ThreadModel
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public HashSet<ThreadsParticipants> ThreadsParticipants { get; set; } = new HashSet<ThreadsParticipants>();
}
```

`ThreadsParticipants.cs` (joining table)

```
public class ThreadsParticipants
{
    public int ThreadModelId { get; private set; }

    public ThreadModel ThreadModel { get; private set; } = default!;

    public int ParticipantModelId { get; private set; }

    public ParticipantModel ParticipantModel { get; private set; } = default!;
}
```

And the following configurations `EntityTypeConfiguration`s:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ParticipantModel> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ThreadModel> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ThreadsParticipants> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(tp => new { tp.ThreadModelId, tp.ParticipantModelId });

        builder
            .HasOne(tp => tp.ThreadModel)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(tp => tp.ThreadModelId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .HasOne(tp => tp.ParticipantModel)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(tp => tp.ParticipantModelId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
```

When running `add-migration` the block that creates the ThreadsParticipants table is generated as such:

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "MessageThreadsParticipants",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ThreadModelId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ParticipantModelId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ParticipantModelId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                ThreadModelId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_MessageThreadsParticipants", x => new { x.ThreadModelId, x.ParticipantModelId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_MessageThreadsParticipants_MessageParticipants_ParticipantModelId",
                    column: x => x.ParticipantModelId,
                    principalTable: "MessageParticipants",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_MessageThreadsParticipants_MessageParticipants_ParticipantModelId1",
                    column: x => x.ParticipantModelId1,
                    principalTable: "MessageParticipants",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_MessageThreadsParticipants_MessageThreads_ThreadModelId",
                    column: x => x.ThreadModelId,
                    principalTable: "MessageThreads",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_MessageThreadsParticipants_MessageThreads_ThreadModelId1",
                    column: x => x.ThreadModelId1,
                    principalTable: "MessageThreads",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Why are these extra foreign key properties generated when I've explicitly specified what my foreign keys are?

Comment: Just to help you in communicating the issue: this is not a many-to-many relationship if you follow EF documentation standards. This is two separate one-to-many relationships (which you functionally use as if it were a many-to-many, but EF doesn't care about your intentions). In the context of EF, many-to-many refers to cases where you don't specify the join table, EF makes it for you and hides it from you. Note that EF Core doesn't support many-to-many right now (original EF does support it).

Comment: Thank you about the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As per @Flater's comment the reason for this was that the configuration was specified twice thus an extra set of columns was created.

---

Actually removing the duplex one-to-many Fluent API configuration from the `ThreadsParticipants` entity type configuration solves this issue and the extra properties are no longer created. When this portion of the config is removed
EF uses naming convetions to figure the relationship out so there's no need to explicitly state the relationship details.

```
    builder
        .HasOne(tp => tp.ThreadModel)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(tp => tp.ThreadModelId)
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .HasOne(tp => tp.ParticipantModel)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(tp => tp.ParticipantModelId)
        .IsRequired();
```

This leads me to think that there is a property name mismatch that is causing all the trouble.

Comment: I suspect it's not so much a mismatch as it is a matter of appending the modelbuilder configuration twice (by convention and explicitly). But regardless, good to see you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The thing there is this, you have a set of foreign keys which are also serving as a composite key for that table. Entity framework has to find a way to resolve some disputes of naming. You could add data annotations explicitly to the model to suppress this issue.

```
[ForeignKey("ThreadModel")]
public int ThreadModelId { get; private set; }
```

And also for the other property
Why not state your full relationship by adding

```
//...
.WithMany(x => x.ThreadsParticipants)
//...
```

Comment: According to EF's convention standards, when the FK property name is `name of nav prop + "Id"`, EF will automatically assume that these two are linked. Your code isn't wrong but by EF conventions it is redundant.